# Adding 1000+ markers from json to google map makes the android app very slow and struck

Tags: android, json, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

In my application am loading 1000+ location form JSON to google map using markers but when i run my application it shows all the markers perfectly but when i tried to zoom  or drag the map it get two slow  and get struck any solution to solve this ??
     The webservice response looks like this given below

```
    {
               "DateTime": "8/4/2015 7:27:32 PM",
               "IME": "865733024065062",
               "IsActivated": null,
               "Latitude": "13.0115833333333",
               "Longitude": "80.2151833333333",
               "RegistrationNo": "AMvTS_01"
           },
           {
               "DateTime": "8/5/2015 12:28:17 PM",
               "IME": "887766554433711",
               "IsActivated": null,
               "Latitude": "16.060578",
               "Longitude": "73.489748",
               "RegistrationNo": "TN_TEST_803"
           },
           {
               "DateTime": "8/5/2015 12:28:17 PM",
               "IME": "887766554433567",
               "IsActivated": null,
               "Latitude": "9.722656",
               "Longitude": "76.287158",
               "RegistrationNo": "TN_TEST_659"
           },
           {
               "DateTime": "8/5/2015 12:28:17 PM",
               "IME": "887766554433740",
               "IsActivated": null,
               "Latitude": "14.895189",
               "Longitude": "74.103996",
               "RegistrationNo": "TN_TEST_832"
           },
           {
               "DateTime": "8/5/2015 12:28:17 PM",
               "IME": "887766554433017",
               "IsActivated": null,
               "Latitude": "12.688946",
               "Longitude": "80.217097",
               "RegistrationNo": "TN_TEST_048"
           },
           {
               "DateTime": "8/5/2015 12:28:17 PM",
               "IME": "887766554433769",
               "IsActivated": null,
               "Latitude": "8.887102",
               "Longitude": "76.591018",
               "RegistrationNo": "TN_TEST_861"
           }

and this is my mapfragment code given below


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream; 
import java.io.InputStreamReader; 
import java.net.HttpURLConnection; 
import java.net.URL; 
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap; 
import java.util.List; 
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity; 
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse; 
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException; 
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient; 
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet; 
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient; 
import org.json.JSONArray; 
import org.json.JSONException; 
import org.json.JSONObject; 

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Circle; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CircleOptions; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions; 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions; 

import android.app.ActionBar; 
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.Fragment; 
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.ProgressDialog; 
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.graphics.Color; 
import android.location.Location; 
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.Uri; 
import android.os.AsyncTask; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.StrictMode; 
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log; 
import android.view.LayoutInflater; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.ViewGroup; 
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements LocationListener, OnMapClickListener, OnMapLongClickListener, OnMarkerDragListener{ 
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "ExampleApp"; 

    private MapView mMapView; 
    private GoogleMap mMap; 
    private Bundle mBundle; 
    private static final String SERVICE_URL = "http://203.109.107.139/primevts/vtsservice.svc/data"; 
    JSONObject json = null; 
    JSONArray jsonarray = null; 
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog; 
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist1; 
    private Timer timer;
    static String LONG = "Long"; 
    static String LAT = "Lat"; 
    ArrayList<String> ct; 
    public double latt = 0; 
    public double lng = 0; 
    public ArrayList<Integer> dLat; 
    private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
    private Handler handler;
    private Marker marker;
    private HashMap<String, Marker> mMarkers = new HashMap<>();
int value=1;
    // LatLngBounds values ; 
    double latitude, longitude; 
    String ime,reg; 
    boolean markerClicked;

    // LatLng val; 

    static HashMap<String, String> datas; 

    static HashMap<String, String> map; 
    String[] latlngvalues;
  //  LocationManager locman;
    Context context;
     View rootView;

    public MapFragment() { 
    } 

    @Override 
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_one, container, false); 


        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity()); 

        mMapView = (MapView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView); 
        mMapView.onCreate(mBundle); 

        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity()); 

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) { 
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder() 
            .permitAll().build(); 
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
        } 

        new DownloadJSON().execute(); 
        setUpMapIfNeeded(rootView);

        /* handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 new DownloadJSON().execute(); 
                    setUpMapIfNeeded(rootView); 

                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Data Updated!!!! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 Log.e("Data in Log", "");
            }
        }, 1000);
        */
         final Handler handler = new Handler();
            timer = new Timer();
            TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            //mMap.clear();
                        // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Data Updated!!!! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         new DownloadJSON().execute(); 
                            setUpMapIfNeeded(rootView); 

                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 20000, 20000);




        /*LocationManager locman = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        //locman.requestLocationUpdates(minTime, minDistance, criteria, intent);
        locman.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10, this);*/



        return rootView; 
    } 

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded(View inflatedView) { 

        if (mMap == null) { 
            mMap = ((MapView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.mapView)).getMap(); 
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); 
              mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
              .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
              .title("Marker")
              .draggable(true)
              .snippet("Hello")
              .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                      .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW)));
            mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
            markerClicked = false;


            Location myLocation = mMap.getMyLocation(); 
            if (mMap != null) {  
                //mMap.clear();

                // setUpMap(); 
                mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() { 

                    @Override 
                    public void onMyLocationChange(Location arg0) { 

                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

                        final LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder(); 
                //  mMap.clear();
                        if(marker!=null){
                            marker.remove();
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < arraylist1.size(); i++) { 
                            final LatLng position = new LatLng(Double 
                                    .parseDouble(arraylist1.get(i).get("Latitude")), 
                                    Double.parseDouble(arraylist1.get(i).get( 
                                            "Longitude"))); 
                            String ime1 = arraylist1.get(i).get("RegistrationNo");
                            final MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions() 
                            .position(position); 
                            //mMap.addMarker(options); 
                            mMap.addMarker(options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory .fromResource(R.drawable.buspng)).anchor(0.0f, 1.0f).title(ime1));
                             // marker=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory .fromResource(R.drawable.buspng)).title(ime1));


                            //options.title(ime1);
                            builder.include(position); 

                        } if(value==1){
                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(), arg0 
                                .getLongitude()); 
                        //mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); 

                        //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(newLatLnglatLng)); 
                        // mMap.setOnMapClickListener(null); 
                        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(null); 
                        //mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(9)); 
                        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(latLng)      // Sets the center of the map to Mountain View
                        .zoom(10)                   // Sets the zoom
                        .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
                        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                        value++;
                        }
                    } 
                }); 

            } 
        } 
    } 

    /*  protected void retrieveAndAddCities() throws IOException { 
        HttpURLConnection conn = null; 
        final StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder(); 
        try { 

            URL url = new URL(SERVICE_URL); 
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()); 

            int read; 
            char[] buff = new char[1024]; 
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) { 
                json.append(buff, 0, read); 
            } 
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to service", e); 
            throw new IOException("Error connecting to service", e); 
        } finally { 
            if (conn != null) { 
                conn.disconnect(); 
            } 
        } 
        new DownloadJSON().execute(); 

    } */

    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { 
        String result=""; 
        @Override 
        protected void onPreExecute() { 
            super.onPreExecute(); 
        }

        @Override 
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) { 
            try { 
                arraylist1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); 

                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser(); 
                String result = ""; 

                json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(SERVICE_URL); 

                try { 
                    arraylist1.clear(); 

                    jsonarray = json.getJSONArray("SingleIMEs"); 
                    Log.d("Haaaaaaaaaaaa", "" + json); 

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) { 
                        Log.d("H11111111111111111111111111", 
                                "" + jsonarray.length()); 
                        map = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
                        json = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i); 

                        latitude = json.getDouble("Latitude"); 
                        longitude = json.getDouble("Longitude"); 
                        ime = json.getString("IME");
                        reg=json.getString("RegistrationNo");
                        map.put("Latitude", json.getString("Latitude")); 
                        Log.e("CHECKLAT",""+json.getString("Latitude") );
                        map.put("Longitude", json.getString("Longitude")); 
                        Log.e("CHECKLONG",""+json.getString("Longitude") );
                     map.put("RegistrationNo", json.getString("RegistrationNo"));
                        map.put("IME", json.getString("IME"));
                        arraylist1.add(map); 
                    } 

                } catch (JSONException e) { 
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString()); 
                    result="Error"; 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                } 
            }catch(Exception e){ 
                result="Error"; 
            } 

            return null; 
        } 

        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) { 

            // mProgressDialog.dismiss(); 

        } 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onResume() { 
        super.onResume(); 
        mMapView.onResume(); 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onPause() { 
        super.onPause(); 
        mMapView.onPause(); 
    } 
    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override 
    public void onDestroy() { 
        mMapView.onDestroy(); 
    super.onDestroy(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   /* Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onLocationUpdated!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("onLocationUpdated!!!","");
        new DownloadJSON().execute(); 
        setUpMapIfNeeded(rootView);*/

    }


    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(arg0));

          markerClicked = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDrag(Marker arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    } 


}
```

Comment: If your ws can pass to you the json with a sort of coordinates query, you can load 50 markers in a radius with that coordinates center and when the user moves the camera, you can request new markers to the ws passing the new coordinates.

Comment: Fondesa:can you please give me sample code??

Answer (score 0):

First you save in List of MarkerOptions your JSON info, when you get it

```
final List<MarkerOptions> markerOptionsList = new ArrayList<>(arraylist1.size());
for (int i = 0; i < arraylist1.size(); i++) {
    final LatLng position = new LatLng(
            Double.parseDouble(arraylist1.get(i).get("Latitude")),
            Double.parseDouble(arraylist1.get(i).get("Longitude")));
    String ime1 = arraylist1.get(i).get("RegistrationNo");
    final MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(position)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.buspng))
            .anchor(0.0f, 1.0f)
            .title(ime1);
    markerOptionsList.add(options);
}
```

Then, instead of OnMyLocationChangeListener use OnCameraChangeListener

```
mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
        mMap.clear();
        LatLngBounds bounds = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
        for (MarkerOptions markerOptions : markerOptionsList) {
            if (bounds.contains(markerOptions.getPosition())) {
                mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

You will clear map and add only visible markers

Comment: pengrad:no its not working for me  ,no marker is getting displayed when tried your solution .please tell me any alternative solution.

Comment: @ganesang i think you did something wrong, post all your mapfragment code